# Does the gravity affect voltage in a circuit?

Tags: gravity, particle-physics, electrons

The electric current is a flow of electrons, which have mass (small, but it is still a mass). So, considering a planar circuit, do the properties of the electric current (voltage, intensity) change with the orientation of the circuit with respect to the ground? I would expect some difference between the cases where the circuit is parallel or perpendicular to the ground.

Comment: I don't know the answer (I guess the influence of gravity in very small in front of the other forces), but you could calculate the order of magnitude ($m_1m_2G/r^2$) and compare it with the other forces.

Comment: I am aware of the fact that the influence is probably so small that it is even almost impossible to measure, but my primary concern was if, at least theoretically, there is an influence.

Comment: In a highly curved spacetime, I suspect there is a significant effect however, I've never given it any thought.  Maybe someone here has.

Answer (score 5):

Be careful to compare the same quantity. You ask if gravity (a force) affects the voltage (a potential energy). These are related but not identical. For a first round comparison, check out the forces due to gravity and a standard voltage (1 Volt over a distance of 1 cm):

First, the gravitational force on an electron at the surface of the Earth:
$$F_g = mg = 9\times10^{-30} \mathrm{N},$$
compared to the force on an electron due to the voltage of 1 V over a distance of 1 cm:
$$F_V = E*q = 1 \frac{\mathrm{V}}{\mathrm{cm}} * q_e = 2\times10^{-17} \mathrm{N}.$$

The forces are quite different in magnitude (as you added in comment). They can probably be measured but I don't know of such results off the top of my head.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Here is your first upvote.

Comment: As you say the effect is very very small. This is fun to know : http://home.web.cern.ch/about/updates/2012/06/full-moon-pulls-lhc-its-protons .. There was never a question that the beam was pulled by the moon :) .