# Does gravity affects on electrons in a noticeable way?

Tags: experimental-physics, soft-question

Is there a way to force a free electron move in a low speed in order to observe it actually hitting 'on the floor'?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  What do you mean by **actually** 'hitting the floor'?  Why does something need to be moving slowly to hit the floor?  What does this have to do with gravity?

Comment: Obviously it doesn't but I can't imagine how we could notice the motion of free electron under the force of gravity if it moves very fast under a magnetic force in a tube-I think that it would do all the run till the end without being possible to notice the gravity's affect on it.

Comment: Probably related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146214/

Comment: Much easier to do with protons or neutrons, which is how some proposals to verify the direction of gravity acting on anti-matter have been frames (in terms of anti-protons or anti-hydrogen).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

William Fairbank conducted an experiment in the 1980s that demonstrated that electrons fall in a gravitational field just like their mass would imply.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? This NAS document only references his work in the 60s and says that they never completed the work to measure the effect of gravity on electrons and positrons. http://www.nasonline.org/publications/biographical-memoirs/memoir-pdfs/fairbank-william.pdf

Comment: @John I studied this question about 10 years ago and my answer was based upon my memory from that time. Fairbanks and his group continued to tweak this experiment until shortly before his death in 1989. The original claim was that they established normal gravitational behavior for both the electron and the positron. After his death his team reached the conclusion that their result was not definitive for the positron  but was got the electron

Comment: @John The obit of Fairbank published in PT summarizes the situation as understood at that time