# Are electrons affected by gravity?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, mass, electrons

Again, probably a very naive question but just wanted to make sure. Are electrons affected by gravity? I was hoping someone could point me in the direction of some experiments that prove this.

Comment: Possibly related :https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/222998/does-gravity-affects-on-electrons-in-a-noticeable-way

Comment: Keep your eye on [this experiment](https://www.google.com/search?q=Sharping+and+Chiao+win+DARPA+Grant+for+Gravity+Wave+Based+Communications).  The apparatus involves droplets of superfluid helium carying a charge, such that the repulsion of the electric force is exactly in equilibrium with the attraction of gravity.

Comment: There is this 1967 Witteborn, Fairbank classical experiment: http://xdel.ru/downloads/lgbooks/fairbank_falling_electrons.pdf with "force was shown to be less than 0.09mg" conclusion ...

Answer (score 13):

Yes, they are affected by gravity. At least they should, since they have mass. However as far as I am aware there is no experiment that directly showed how gravity affects electrons.

One problem is that electrons have a tiny mass and the gravitational force is much much weaker than the Coulomb force, making it difficult to observe it.

The closest to a proof is the determination of the ratio of charge to mass of the electron ($e/m$) from the radius of an electron beam in a homogeneous magnetic field. Together with [Millikan's Oil Drop Experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_drop_experiment) which measured the electric charge of the electron, this provides a number for the electron mass.

However this mass is the inertial mass of the electron. For all we know, inertial mass is equal to the gravitational mass, but if you question this, I believe there is no "proof".

Comment: "The gravitational force is much much weaker than the Coulomb force" - indeed, it is of the order of $10^{40}$ times weaker in a typical laboratory experiment, which is why it is ignored when modelling most electromagnetic effects!

Comment: "*[...] they should, since they have mass.*"  Photons don't have (rest) mass, yet they are affected by gravity. If you accept General Relativity, then everything is affected by gravity.

Answer (score 7):

By [equivalence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle), everything is affected by gravity, just like everything is affected by inertial forces. This includes electrons.

I've noticed the [quantum-gravity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-gravity) tag. You don't need quantum gravity if you are considering weak gravitational fields, because you can treat them as a classical background, even if you are considering quantum-mechanical nature of some objects (like electrons) in such gravitational fields.

Comment: yeah, that was naive. I was going for the angle that perhaps measuring gravitational effects on quantum objects like electrons might yield some knowledge about quantum gravity.

Comment: FYI: quantum-gravity tag has been removed.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Electrons have mass and everything with mass is affected by gravitation(gravity).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_drop_experiment

Comment: The mass in the oil drop experiment is the mass of the oil drop and not of the electron.

Comment: That's probably a fair point but it doesn't change the simple answer of 'yes'. It is an experiment worth noting IMHO.

Comment: Why is my answer down-voted? it's the same as the other answer only posted sooner and with fewer words.(more concise)