# What evidence is there for the gravitational acceleration of a free electron?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, experimental-physics, electrons, atomic-physics

According to Newtonian gravity (in the absence of other forces or obstacles) a free electron (not moving at high velocity) should (because it has mass) fall towards the Earth's centre with the same acceleration as a hammer, feather, atom, neutron, proton, or any other massive object. (I think that General Relativity predicts a similar behavior).

I would like to know what evidence (experiemental or observational) there is, if any, to demonstrate that electrons do conform to Newtonian gravity in the same way that more massive objects do.

I suspect that it is difficult to obtain such evidence at Earth's surface because of the presence of electric and magnetic fields which would be difficult to compensate for at the required accuracy.

Comment: Would the famous oil drop experiment qualify? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_drop_experiment

Comment: @KF Gauss I assume that (given the mass of the electron is so small compared to the mass of a Milikan oil droplet) the gravitational force ($F = m*a$) on the electron is negligible compared to the gravitational force on the droplet.

Comment: That's fair. Do you limit your question to electrons, or would another charged particle (proton, muon, etc.) be OK?

Comment: @KF Gauss - mainly electron but also interested in positron.

Answer (score 1):

There are several experiments and some have the similar approach: In  the  electron  experiment  the  gravitational  potential  difference  $mgh$ is  cancelled  by the  gravitationally  induced  electric  potential  from  the  electrons  on  the  walls and therefore  in  pure  gravity one  would  measure  0 acceleration. Basically the system consists of a hollow tube and electron source.
For more experimental details I suggest the article [Experiments to determine the Force of Gravity on Single Electrons and Positrons](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://s3.cern.ch/inspire-prod-files-b/bbbee44751a98c26f6e03d494698b715&ved=2ahUKEwiBjM3X1__rAhWBnVwKHSWcCx0QFjALegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw2M0Q-SgYCvGZVkshvV59s7) by Fred C. Witteborn & William M. Fairbank.

Comment: Thanks for the source (which I sadly cannot access at present).  [Elsewhere](www.nasonline.org/publications/biographical-memoirs/memoir-pdfs/fairbank-william.pdf) I found this:- "the effort to measure the force of gravity on electrons and positrons was never
completed although four Ph.d. theses were generated by the work. the measurement of the force of gravity on falling, singly ionized helium atoms was convincing; the force on
electrons and positrons less so...(contd)

Comment: (contd)..."in order to understand how it might have been possible to measure the force of gravity on such light particles, surface states inside copper tubeswere invoked to shield the interior of the tube from the known patch effect electric fields. follow-up work by the last two graduate students did not confirm the earlier results; however, there were indications of a transition occurring within the copper drift tube at low temperatures""

Comment: Many thanks, got it :)  Also see answer & comments by Lewis Miller  "Fairbanks and his group continued to tweak this experiment until shortly before his death in 1989. The original claim was that they established normal gravitational behavior for both the electron and the positron. After his death his team reached the conclusion that their result was not definitive for the positron but was got the electron" in this (closed) post https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/222998/does-gravity-affects-on-electrons-in-a-noticeable-way

Comment: A recent historical review by Michael Holzscheiter: [https://indico.cern.ch/event/361413/contributions/1776296/attachments/1137816/1628821/WAG2015.pdf](https://indico.cern.ch/event/361413/contributions/1776296/attachments/1137816/1628821/WAG2015.pdf)